# JS выбор блока контента внешней ссылкой

Tags: javascript, jquery, ссылки, меню

На главной странице (stom-mva ru) одни пункты меню(ссылки) ведут на другие страницы, другие пункты - меняют на div'ы (основной "контент") с помощью этого кода:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.m').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.content').each(function() {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        });
        var block = $(this).attr('href');
        $(block).css('display', 'block');
    });
});
</script>
```

и

```
<li ><a href="#about" class="m" id="abo"> </a></li> 
    <li ><a href="uslugi.html"  id="usl"></a></li>
    <li ><a href="gallery.html"  id="gall" ></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#contacts" class="m" id="cont" ></a></li>
```

...

```
<div class="content" id="about">
```

...

Вопрос: как сделать так, что бы ЭТО меню корректно работало и с других страниц сайта?
Т.е. чтоб и на других страницах ссылки, которые ведут на "дополнительные" div'ы на главной, срабатывали правильно, и показывали автоматом нужные блоки?

Как я думаю, что тут может быть 2 пути: 
1. правильно указать в ссылках меню эти "динамические" блоки. (но как? знаю, только, что такое используется в CMS, но там же php!, и будут ли они тогда ЧПУ?)
2. в скрипт допилить функцию "срабатывания" и при переходе с "внешних" ссылок.
Но как?

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то обычно используются относительные пути ( ./somePage.html). А что по поводу якорей (#contacts, #about) то нужно на новом месте присвоить каким-то либо элементам соостветвующие id (contacts, about)

Comment: id присвоены, и это работает, если вызывать их с главной. Если же мы находимся на другой странице, то при нажатии "на них", выдаётся только главная страница, а контент на ней - не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Пощелкал и выяснил, что у вас просто есть простое "несовпадение" при работе скрипта. Как это получается - вы когда перемещаетесь с "услуги" на "страхование", то ссылка имеет вид index.html#insurance. Ссылка то вполне рабочая, однако скрипт, который его обрабатывает срабатывает ПОСЛЕ прогрузки страницы.

И даже больше - скрипт обрабатывает НАЖАТИЕ (click) на элемент, а ведь при переходе на страницу вы на элемент не нажимаете уже - вы страницу загружаете. А вот при её загрузке обработки нет (ведь когда ты открываешь страхование вы переходите обратно на страницу index.html).

Решение достаточно простое - нужно поставить обработку на загрузку страницы, которая будет обрабатывать url. Если в урл есть айдишник ( #isurance), то должен срабатывать скрипт, который вы написали в вопросе. Пример события, который запускает твой код после загрузки DOM - `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Примерно так всё и представлял. Теперь буду разбираться, как это правильно сделать. Простое добавление этой строки даёт срабатывание со второго раза. Сначала всё-таки выкидвает на главную, а потом - всё норм.

Comment: @Oleg ну так все верно - сначала страница загружается, потом загружается скрипт, который вешает обработчик на нажатие click. Поэтому и со второго раза. Я бы посоветовал перейти на одно из решений - или же полностью "скрываемый" контент (т.е. грузится все, но показывается только часть) , или же простые ссылки на другие страницы. Или вообще по "черному" - по клику загружать контент из page#N.html в блоки при помощи ajax например (но это слегка нерационально).